# how to avoid divs to overlap when positioned absolute in a relative container

Tags: php, jquery, css, css-position

HTML

```
<td title='10:00 AM-wed 09-01-2013'><div style="position:relative;height:60px">
        <div style="position:absolute;top:00px;" class='entry'>Demo patient</div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:20px;" class='entry'>New patient</div>
        <div style="position:absolute;top:40px;" class='entry'>fool patient</div>
</div></td>
```

pic

[image]

PHP used to generate entries

```
echo"<div style='position:absolute;top:".date("i", strtotime($data['time_booked']))."px;'>{$data['name']}</div>";
```

i made a simple a jquery/php day scheduler(calendar), as show above.

as u can see i have parent div height:60px(1px each min) and position relative
then i position child divs absolute according to its min (eg: demo patient is 10:00 so top:00px , fool patient is 10:40 so its top:40px).
this is working fine except when there is overlapping time.. example if i have 2 entries
same time then both will be positioned on top of each other.

**Question** how can i avoid this ? like google calendar if 2 booking exist the are moved side by side instead of on top of each other.

### thanks

**Problem solved:**

using [This plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/overlaps/demos) and following code

```
var n=$('div.entry').overlaps().length;var vol=(100/n);var round=0;
    $('div.entry').overlaps().each(function(){
        $(this).css('left',((vol-1)*round)+'%');
        $(this).css('width',(vol-n)+'%')
        round=round+1;
    });
```

Now it works perfectly as google calendar :D.. thanks all

Comment: you no say? i guess i taged it jquery for that reason, what im interested in is know-how

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried? Or attempted to try?

Comment: i got no clue how to detect if a div is overlapping other so nop

Comment: a jsfiddle would be not too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a jquery solution to check if any elements overlaps then you can use this plugin [brandonaaron/jquery-overlaps](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-overlaps). You can do the checks for each element to check if any overlap then perform the function that will reposition the events within the parent

Answer (score 1):

I would change your output to be along the lines of this:

```
<td title='10:00 AM-wed 09-01-2013'><div style="position:relative;height:60px">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:00px;"><span>Demo patient</span></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:20px;"><span>New patient</span><span>2nd patient at this time</span></div>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:40px;"><span>fool patient</span></div>
</div></td>
```

Then they will float next to each other

Comment: The text '00px' comes from the original post, it works just fine, and aligns the values nicely.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the solution to be? Do you want the items to be positioned *after* each other, or *next to* each other? In any case, you probably just need to tweak your positioning a little to take into account the possibility for overlap.

Don't use the raw time to position them, but do your overlap resolution first, see which elements overlap, give them a relative position, ie:

```
(0,0)
(1,0)   (1,1)  // overlap here
(2,0)
```

then convert the relative positions to pixel coordinates. You should now also know how high your column should be to fit all the elements.

Comment: wt i want is IF there is overlap then both overlapped divs are side by side ELSE keep them poistion according to time..(just like google calendar for example)